# Strange interaction between listings and sections

Tags: listings

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{shell}{}{}
%\usepackage{verbatim}
%\let\shell\verbatim
%\let\endshell\endverbatim
\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Test1}

\begin{shell}
test
\end{shell}
Some text

\subsubsection{Test2}

More text, Test2 has no spacing above

\subsubsection{Test3}

Looks ok
\end{document}
```

When I compile this I get

[image]

where did the space above section `Test2` go? If I don't use `listings`, say the commented stuff, things are ok.

Any ideas?

Versions listed below.

```
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
listings.sty    2013/08/26 1.5b (Carsten Heinz)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
 lstmisc.sty    2013/08/26 1.5b (Carsten Heinz)
listings.cfg    2013/08/26 1.5b listings configuration
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A `lstlisting` environment doesn't reset `\if@nobreak` when immediately after a section title. Unfortunately my bug report of some years ago fell into hyperspace.

A “bad” fix is to add yourself the missing action:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fixspacing}{\@nobreakfalse}
\makeatother
\lstnewenvironment{shell}{}{\fixspacing}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Test1}

\begin{shell}
test
\end{shell}
Some text

\subsubsection{Test2}

More text, Test2 has no spacing above

\subsubsection{Test3}

Looks ok
\end{document}
```

A not so clean patch is

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\lst@DeInit{\@nobreakfalse}{}{}
\makeatother

\lstnewenvironment{shell}{}{}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Test1}

\begin{shell}
test
\end{shell}
Some text

\subsubsection{Test2}

More text, Test2 has no spacing above

\subsubsection{Test3}

Looks ok
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the `\lstnewenvironment@` command where the action would be more proper is not patchable, so the fix should really be at the package level. My impression is that `\lst@DeInit` is called in places where `\if@nobreak` ought to be set to false. But I may be wrong.

[image]

Comment: You say »A “bad” fix« - does it have any drawbacks? BTW: I believe `listings` is actively maintained again by Jobst Hoffmann if I'm not mistaken. Maybe there's a chance the bug is getting fixed now :)

Comment: @cgnieder "Bad" in the sense that you need to specify `\fixspacing` in every listing environment you define.

Comment: Thanks, that might explain some odd behaviour I've seen earlier

Comment: I've sent an email to Jobst.