# lstlistings messes up spacing before subsequent section headings

Tags: spacing, listings, verbatim

I'm typesetting a grammar specification for a programming language, which leads to many short snippets of grammar and example code interleaved in the document text.

The issue I observe is that an `lstlisting` has no proper spacing to the following paragraph, and messes up the spacing before all following section headings. See the following screenshot (notice how *0.1.1 Examples* "sticks" to the paragraph):

[image: Original Layout]

Inserting a `description` list after the first listing (uncomment *(A)* in the code) actually resolves the spacing issue of the section heading:

[image: Fixed Layout with Description List]

Changing the first listing (change *(B)* in the code) to `verbatim` resolves the issue entirely and inserts a much desired vertical space before the following paragraph:

[image: Fixed Layout with Verbatim]

To sum up,

- `verbatim` gives me the desired overall layout of the text, whereas
- `lstlistings` looks subpar layout-wise but breaks lines and highlights code nicely.

Am I missing out on something about *lstlistings*? Are there any alternatives that are closer to what *verbatim* does?

---

The following source code produces the above results:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{color,dejavu,listings,paralist}
\lstset{backgroundcolor=\color[gray]{0.90}, aboveskip=0pt, belowskip=0pt}

\begin{document}
\section{Definition}

% (A)
\begin{lstlisting}
definition : name ":" expr
\end{lstlisting}

% (B)
% \begin{description}
% \item[expr] can be any valid expression and is evaluated at compile time until a
%             function, a type, or a constant value is obtained. If this is not
%             possible, the compiler will stop with an error.
% \end{description}

A \emph{definition} is an expression with a label assigned to it. The label
allows other parts of the code to refer to the definition. Only definitions are
exported out of packages and can be referenced from other code.

\subsection{Examples}
\begin{lstlisting}
(a) A: func x -> x*x
(b) B: func x,y -> x*y
(c) C: type Int range 0 to 7
(d) D: 123
(e) E: A(2)
\end{lstlisting}

Where \begin{inparaenum}
    \item is a function with one argument,
    \item is a function with two arguments,
    \item is a type representing integers from 0 to 7,
    \item is the integer constant 123, and
    \item is the integer constant 4
\end{inparaenum}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Thanks for linking to your file, but we, on TeX.SX, like questions to be self-contained. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Have you considered "floating" your listings? Surely, that would improve the look of the output.

Comment: @Jubobs Thanks for the hint, added an example. Floating would indeed solve this issue, but also make the document harder to read since it would break the pattern of (*group name*, *grammar rules*, *description and examples*, …).

Comment: Relevant http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136256/strange-interaction-between-listings-and-sections

Comment: Indeed, the referenced duplicate resolves the issue!